# Relativistic rotational squeezing?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, astrophysics

I would like to consider a sphere rotating at very high angular speeds, such that the speed in its equator would be relativistic.

This is very similar to Ehrenfest paradox situation, except that here is a sphere.

This situation could occur, I imagine, if when an exploding star is sufficiently big to leave a core, this core would have an angular momentum be it from reduction of radius which would increase it, be it from stirring from the explosion. The thing is, its value could be very high, such that it could reach a relativistic regime.

However I am not very concerned on the actual occurrence of this phenomenon not yet, but rather with an effect I am imagining could occur but which I would like to consult before considering it seriously and get into the mathematics.

The question: Can relativistic rotation further squeeze this core? If we imagine it was left with certain angular momentum and equatorial radius such that classically it would exceed light speed, this would imply either there would be a constriction on the radius of the remaining core, either the core would squeeze in the equator and take a shape with the same momentum but not exceeding c in its equator.

More importantly, and maybe easier to reply, has this situation or similar been considered? I would appreciate sources to read on this.

Comment: This paper might be a start http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5015

Comment: I think neutron stars are considered to have rotational speeds, where their equators move at fractions of the speed of light.  Regardless, if you spin a spherical object, the equatorial region will bulge unless the material is infinitely rigid.  The object will no longer be a sphere, but rather an oblate spheroid.

Comment: It seems more likely that the rotation would become non-rigid as the speed of the outer surface approached $c$.

Comment: Another complication is that the coordinate speed of light diminishes in line with gravitational potential. And at a black hole event horizon, it's zero. So if you have a spinning body getting smaller and smaller spinning faster and faster as the coordinate speed of light is decreasing, it sounds to me as if it will [end badly](http://www.nasa.gov/topics/universe/features/shocking-burst.html).

Comment: Would you consider oscillations changed/induced by relativistic rotation to be an answer?

Comment: Sure, but you mean field oscillations? I want to know the effect on the mass distribution, and if it is possible for this mass distribution to be compressed because of its rotation, even if it is just as part of some oscillating process.